# Why same code but different result for non-Roman character String after a specfic date's recompile?

Tags: java

I have the following code which takes a string and generate another string by calling CRC32 method. However the same codes generate different outputs for non-Roman character string before and after a recompile around September 5th. In other words, after this date, the outputs are the same for different compiles, but different comparing to the outputs before this date's compile. The only thing I can think of is the development environment's impact, but my Java version has no change.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( );

        if( item.UID != null && !item.UID.equals( "" ) )
        {
            sb.append( item.UID );
            sb.append( "\t" );
        }

        if( item.LASTNAME != null && !item.LASTNAME.equals( "" ) )
        {
            sb.append( item.LASTNAME );
            sb.append( "\t" );
        }

        if( item.FIRSTNAME != null && !item.FIRSTNAME.equals( "" ) )
        {
            sb.append( item.FIRSTNAME );
        }

        item.UNIQUE_ID_STRING = new String( sb ).toUpperCase( ).trim( );

        CRC32 crc = new CRC32( );
        crc.update( item.UNIQUE_ID_STRING.getBytes( ) );        
        String SERVICE_ID = Long.toString( crc.getValue( ) );
```

Taking the input Arabic character string "12 همام عبد الخالق عبد الغفور" as an example, the output (SERVICE_ID) before the recompile is 6053713010, and the output (SERVICE_ID) after the recompile is 3685688677.

It is under Windows 7 Enterprise, Eclipse Java EE IDE Neon Release 4.6.0. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried specifying an explicit `Charset` to `getBytes()`? e.g. `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. Maybe you're running it on a JVM with a different default encoding.

Comment: things to consider: 1- java update 2- OS reconfiguration 3- running environment change 4- (sometimes OS itself)   <-- has any of them changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `getBytes()` on the input string you do not provide the charset. This will fall back to the system provided one - which may change depending on your setup or external settings / OS updates.

so calling `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead should be more stable

Comment: "should be more stable" yes; but to match the previous behavior, the explicit charset may need to be something else.

Comment: Even though Arabic is unicase, also specify a `toUpperCase(new Locale("ar"))` to have a norm, when encountering a piece of Turkish or whatever. Then the code is cross-platform.